# JPA using Procedure to update and delete

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, stored-procedures, java-stored-procedures

I'm using JPA for my application, and there are security checks on the db table for select, insert, update and delete. In addition, there are procedures to check the security using pass, user_id, table_id and also the table security operations (select, insert, update, delete). There is already procedure to do the insert, update and delete through pass parameters.

What is the best practice in this situation for update and delete. Do I use the entity directly, for example:

```
ex: entityManager.save, entityManager.delete)
```

or do I use the current procedures to do these transactions (insert, update and delete).

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("delete_from_table");
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("table_name", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("row_id", int.class, ParameterMode.IN);
// execute SP
storedProcedure.execute();
......
. 
.
.
```

Comment: Did you check the the database administrator to see what the procedures do? There may be logging done in the background for tracking changes and security, which may be important. If not, then you can just use the JPA methods directly.

Comment: thank you for the reply, yes i have checked, these procedures important because there is a restriction to access the tables with operations, and the database users are different then application users, for that the restriction.

Comment: Since JPA is usually accessing the database through a datasource, which is usually tied to a single database users, app users are being given access to the datasource already, so I assume the database security checks and the overhead aren't going to really be needed.  Providers can be configured to use stored procedures underneath the covers for the CRUD operations, so you can still use your JPA persist, merge, remove and find operations in your application regardless.  This would require custom native configuration outside of JPA though.